# Bash getopts not reading arguments to variables

Tags: bash, getopts

Hi all I think I am going insane. I have the following at the beginning of a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts i:o:c:p:g: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        g) genome=${OPTARG};;
        p) poscol=${OPTARG};;
        c) chromcol=${OPTARG};;
        i) inf=${OPTARG};;
        o) outf=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

echo ""
echo "This should be a list of the arguments:"
echo $inf
echo $outf
echo $poscol
echo $chromcol
echo $genome
echo "-----------------------"
```

Yet when I run a test of the code, eg:

```
bash Code.sh -i test.txt -o test.txt -c 0 -p 1 -g testgenome
```

bash returns:

```
This should be a list of the arguments:





-----------------------
```

I literally just copied this section of code from a script where the arguments work fine. Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the described behavior. Your script works fine for me.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Did you copy the command line as well, and if so, from where? Your output is consistent with the command line using something other than hyphens for the flags (like en-dashes, for example).

Comment: @chepner I had thought of this too. I initially copied it from a plaintext text editor, and then typed the command line in manually - same result.

Comment: same cannot reproduce , i tested on MacOs & 3 versions of Debian no issue .
May be you can try in some docker environment  , with a similar command `docker run -it debian:bullseye /bin/bash`

Comment: Works fine on Linux Mint 20, bash 5.0.17(1)-release

Comment: Works fine on Linux Ubuntu 20